# Как выбрать class

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте. Как выбрать этот класс  `class="pm-thumb-fix pm-thumb-145">` с помощью Jquery

Comment: `var $collection = $('.pm-thumb-fix.pm-thumb-145');`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не додумался) только так var collection = $('.pm-thumb-fix.pm-thumb-145');

Comment: @fikos, название переменной с долларом в начале обычно символизирует то, что в переменной валяется dom-элемент или их коллекция. Насколько это распространено и стандартизованно, есть ли это в тех же стандартах гугла - не знаю, в js я не очень глубоко залезаю.

Comment: c $ не сработало